# react-native conditionals for functions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

```
lang(){
    if(this.state.locale === 'hi-IN'){
      return Dialogflow_V2.LANG_HINDI
    }else{return Dialogflow_V2.LANG_ENGLISH_US}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Dialogflow_V2.setConfiguration(
      dialogflowConfig.client_email,
      dialogflowConfig.private_key,
      this.lang(),
      this.state.lang,
      dialogflowConfig.project_id
    );
  }
```

I need to send the language function in my configuration, but it only takes whatever is in the 'else' statement even when my 'if' statement is true.

I also tried to use buttons to setState

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        locale:'',
        lang:'',
    }
}
langHindi(){
    this.setState({locale:'hi-IN'}, {lang:Dialogflow_V2.LANG_HINDI})
  }
langEnglish(){
    this.setState({locale:'en_US'},{lang:Dialogflow_V2.LANG_ENGLISH})
  }

render(){
    return(
    <Button
          title="English"
          color='black'
          onPress={() => this.langEnglish()}
        />
        <Button
          title="Hindi"
          color='black'
          onPress={() => this.langHindi()}
        />
     )
}
```

and pass `this.state.lang` in my config, but get an error saying it needs a function but its getting an object.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: `cDM` is called when the component mounts, not on state changes. You're passing two objects to `setState`, it doesn't take two objects, it takes an object or an object and a function (the callback to run after the state is changed).

Comment: any other way i can change the config?

Comment: Set it when the value changes? No idea if that will *work*, depends on whatever `Dialogflow_V2` is and how it works.